# React Native - Creating sections in a list with clickable link to screen

Tags: react-native, react-native-sectionlist

Im trying to create a `Settings Page` like so in `React Native`:

[image]

Using `SectionList` in `react native`, but im not sure how I pass in a `navigation` to link to another `view`.

For example

- when I click `Edit Profile`, this should take me to another page.
- when I click on `Privacy policy`, this should open webpage with link.

**UPDATED CODE**

settingsNavigator.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";

import SettingsScreen from "../screens/settingsScreen";
import EditProfileScreen from "../screens/editProfileScreen"

const SettingsStack = createStackNavigator();

const SettingsNavigator = () => (
    <SettingsStack.Navigator>
        <SettingsStack.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
        <SettingsStack.Screen name="EditProfileScreen" component={EditProfileScreen} options={{ title: 'Edit Profile' }} />
    </SettingsStack.Navigator>
)

export default SettingsNavigator
```

settingScreen.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, Linking } from 'react-native';
import { Card } from 'react-native-paper'

import Screen from '../Components/Screen'

function SettingsScreen({navigation}) {
    return (
        <Screen style={styles.screen}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate("EditProfileScreen")}>
                <Card style={styles.list} >
                    <Text>Edit Profile</Text>
                </Card>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </Screen>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    list: {
        padding: 20,
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        borderRadius: 5,
        marginTop: 10,
      },
})

export default SettingsScreen
```

editProfileScreen

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

import Screen from '../Components/Screen'

function EditProfileScreen({navigation}) {
    return (
        <Screen style={styles.screen}>
            <Text>Edit Profile Screen</Text>
        </Screen>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    
})

export default EditProfileScreen
```

error im getting:

```
The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"EditProfileScreen"} was not handled by any navigator.

Do you have a screen named 'EditProfileScreen'?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/) for navigating from one screen to another and the `Linking` component of `react-native` open URL in the browser.

**Working App: [Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@xeteke8423/a9d340)**

**App Output:**

[image]

Sample App:

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Linking,
} from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

import { Card } from 'react-native-paper';

import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const url =
  'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65647568/react-native-creating-sections-in-a-list-with-clickable-link-to-screen#65647648';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name={'Home'} component={Home} />

        <Stack.Screen name={'EditProfile'} component={EditProfile} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

const Home = ({ navigation }) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('EditProfile')}>
        <Card style={styles.list}>
          <Text>EditProfile</Text>
        </Card>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => Linking.openURL(url)}>
        <Card style={styles.list}>
          <Text>Privacy Policy</Text>
        </Card>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};
const EditProfile = ({ navigation }) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.text}>EditProfile Screen</Text>
    </View>
  );
};


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  list: {
    padding: 20,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    borderRadius: 5,
    marginTop: 10,
  },
});
```

Comment: Ranteke, I tried implementing your solution into my current project and got the following issues (updated question with code)

Answer (score 1):

It depends which navigation module you use. I recommend [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org).
With React Navigation, you can access the navigation object on each screen via the props.Provided the screen exists in the stack or you have navigated before.

You can navigate through an onPress event handler like:

```
onPress={() => navigation.navigate('EditProfile')}
```

Do not forget to read navigation from the props beforehand

```
function SettingsPage({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
     // UI THINGS
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to research Routers. I used components `<NavLink>` and `<Link>` to do something like this.

https://www.newline.co/@andreeamaco/how-to-handle-navigation-in-your-app-with-react-router-link--088f82d3

Here is a great video on that:
A Prerequisite (Probably Optional):
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eofpZPRUnP8
Here is the actual implementation:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5pt_igBTCsI&t=8s